# R: get function in a data.table with ifelse criteria

Tags: r, data.table

I have this sample data

```
rawdata <- data.table(  name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),  btax = c(2000, 200, 300, 600, 700),  rate = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.5))
```

I am taking input from excel where the cells are named region.
these named ranges tells which columns are available and which ones to use from the  `rawdata`
.
Let say I am trying to calculate net figure after tax. I have the tax rate always given but the amount is some times after tax and some times in gross.
so using an ifelse I need to create a column after tax which is use after tax if it is given else calculate it. and vice verse.

both gross and net columns are required with either of them given.

This is the code which I have tried.

```
beforetax<-read.xlsx(xlsxFile="//xxxxxxxx/Book1.xlsx",namedRegion="beforetax",   colNames=FALSE)[,1];
aftertax<-read.xlsx(xlsxFile="//xxxxxxxxx/Book1.xlsx",namedRegion="aftertax",   colNames=FALSE)[,1];
taxrate<-read.xlsx(xlsxFile="//xxxxxxxxx/Book1.xlsx",namedRegion="taxrate",   colNames=FALSE)[,1];

rawdata[, net := get(beforetax)*get(rate)];
rawdata[, net := get(aftertax)];
```

column D shows the name of the cell of column E

[image: excel snip]

Output should look like this:

```
data.table(  name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),  btax = c(2000, 200, 300, 600, 700),  rate = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.5), BeforeTax1 = c(2000, 200, 300, 600, 700), AfterTax1 = c(1400, 160, 270, 570, 350))
```

Comment: This is almost reproducible but the critical part isn't. Could you post the output of `dput(beforetax)` (or a minimal version of it which uses ranges in the relevant way)? You might also want to check out the [Programming on `data.table`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html) vignette, particularly the recent changes with `env`.

Comment: ```> dput(rawdata$btax)```
```c(2000, 200, 300, 600, 700)```

Comment: Using get() is probably not the best solution here.  Possibly conditionally joining the before/after tax rate data and setting the net rate? More details are needed to offer a solution, including the column names and/or sample output of your other data files.

Comment: edited with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rewritten now that I think I understand the problem]

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(data.table)

rawdata <- data.table(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                      btax = c(2000, 200, 300, 600, 700),
                      rate = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.5))   

# metadata (read from Excel using openxlsx::read.xlsx)
beforetax <- "btax"
aftertax  <- NULL
taxrate   <- "rate"
```

**Solution (`data.table` < V1.15.0):**

```
# advisable to check one or other of before/after col names is NULL 
stopifnot(sum(sapply(list(beforetax, aftertax), is.null)) == 1L)

if (is.null(aftertax)) {
  rawdata[, ':=' (BeforeTax1 = get(beforetax),
                  AfterTax1  = get(beforetax) * (1 - get(taxrate)))]
} else {
  rawdata[, ':=' (BeforeTax1 = get(aftertax) / (1 - get(taxrate)),
                  AfterTax1  = get(aftertax))]
}
```

**Result:**

```
> rawdata
     name  btax  rate BeforeTax1 AfterTax1
   <char> <num> <num>      <num>     <num>
1:      a  2000  0.30       2000      1400
2:      b   200  0.20        200       160
3:      c   300  0.10        300       270
4:      d   600  0.05        600       570
5:      e   700  0.50        700       350
```

**Alternative solution (`data.table` >= V1.15.0)** avoiding `get` which is now discouraged in favour of `env` (and also using the `let` alias for `':='`):

```
if (is.null(aftertax)) {
  rawdata[, let(BeforeTax1 = b, AfterTax1 = b * (1 - r)),
          env = list(r = taxrate, b = beforetax)]
} else {
  rawdata[, let(BeforeTax1 = a / (1 - r), AfterTax1 = a),
          env = list(r = taxrate, a = aftertax)]
}
```

See this vignette on [Programming with data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html) as mentioned by @SamR

Comment: Of the 3 vectors tax rate, beforetax and aftertax. Taxrate is always available but either of beforetax or aftertax is given. And I need both these columns in the rawdata table by calculation.

Comment: @Mohit, isn't that exactly what I've given you?

Comment: So. I am saying that sometimes the entire vector beforetax is given and sometimes the entire vector aftertax is given. There won’t be any omissions in the vector. Entire rawdata is imported in r from excel.

Comment: And there is input from other excel file specifying which ones are available and which ones are not as in the screenshot above. Happy to explain more. Let me know.

Comment: @Mohit I think I finally understand.  Please try the new answer and see if it works.

Comment: I cant thank you enough. This works perfectly. 2 things. 1) I have tested it. Works well without error even when both the vectors are given. 2) I have been using a get/mget a lot in my codes. is it advisable to not use get/mget with data.table. I like env & let btw.

Comment: Please accept the answer in that case, and sorry I got the wrong end of the stick first time round! 1) Yes, if before and after data are both present and you ignore the `stopifnot` check then it will work, though it will still calculate `AfterTax1` from the `taxrate` and `beforetax` columns (rather than just taking the values in the `aftertax` column).

Comment: 2) `get` might be harmless in this case but in general it can block certain `data.table` optimisations and create other problems. Bottom line from a user point of view: `env` is a new general-purpose way of injecting/substituting column names (and more) into `DT[i,j,by]` and we should adopt it.

Comment: @Mohit, I got it the wrong way round in the first comment above. I mean that if neither of `beforetax` and `aftertax` are `NULL` then it will use the `else` part of the logic, i.e. it will calculate `BeforeTax1` from the data in the `aftertax` and `rate` columns

Comment: Please upvote the question as well. So as we both benefit… lol